# How to save QR Code Details to ListView

Tags: android

My Activity Class

```
package com.sp.scannerview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScannerView extends Activity implements 
ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner_view);


}

public void scan(View view) {
    zXingScannerView=new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(zXingScannerView);
    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
}
```

I am doing a qrcode scanner program. I managed to be able to scan qr codes using the phone camera by following a tutorial on youtube. Now I was wondering if I could save the details to a listview on a separate activity. How do i go about this? Just started on android studio so am abit new here.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here :

- You want to open the details activity right after the scan : you can use an `Intent`, with which you can pass the data through the extras.
- You don't want to open this activity right now : you can store the data in the `SharedPreferences`. This way, once you open the details activity, you retrieve the needed data.

### EDIT

Here is how to use an `Intent` : 
The constructor takes two arguments : the source activity and the destination one.

*Example :*

`new Intent(MyActivity.this, MySecondActivity.class)`

Once you a new `Intent` object, here is how to pass data :

`intent.putExtra(<extra_key>, <data>)`

In your `MySecondActivity`, you can access the intent's extras like this :
`getIntent().getExtras()`.

And you're done! You can check the [Android Developers documentation here on how passing and retrieving extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

Comment: i would like to open the details activity after the scan

Comment: so the listview i assume is the 2nd activity?

Comment: Yes indeed. I assumed that when you are scanning your QR code, you are in the `MyActivity`. So, once scan done, you can open the `MySecondActivity` to display the QR code's details.

Comment: hi there i managed to follow a simpler code on youtube on qr scanning. i have replaced the previous code with the new one. how do i go about saving the toast message to listview?

Comment: Same as previously : use an intent to pass the text from `Toast` to your other activity.

Comment: so i create a 2nd activity with a listview and use intent.putExtra(<extra_key>,data) in my first activity.

Comment: so i declare new intent in 1st activity followed by intent.putExtra(<extra_key>, <data>). Then in 2nd activity, i just put getIntent().getExtras() in my code? sorry am abit slow in understanding

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras()` will return you a `Bundle` object, where all extras you put in your first activity are stored.

I assume your data is string,with the key _myKey_. You would do `getIntent().getExtras().getString("mykey")` to get your QR code details.